# Tool to show how to pronounce words "lexical stress"

Tags: english

I'm looking for a tool that can show how to pronounce words in this style

I see that google can do this with words but I would like to get same result for longer texts. I've tried to search but couldn't find anything relevant. I belive I am failing to use the right terms.

I've found some online converters that converts to phonetic but those is almost unreadable that's why I like the other form much more like on the picture.

[image: Hello]

Or if someone could explain to me what this kind of pronunciation is actually called in contrast to other phonetics so I can filter my search to maybe get better results, it would also help :)

Comment: What you are looking for is something to help you with "sentence intonation". Lexical stress is for single words. Sentence intonation means how to pronounce words in the context of an utterance, also called: stress patterns.. You could start here: https://www.britishcouncil.org/voices-magazine/how-english-learners-can-improve-intonation